# Is there a way to keep only valid options when there are two drop down fields?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I have a an android app which I have done, it has two drop down menus. I have coded it using phone gap in eclipse.. one is "source" and other is "destination" . I have created a table and made many entries. The problem I face here is when i select a source and a particular destination which have no entry i get undefined as i haven't made such entry in the table. What I want is when i select a source, only valid options should come in the destination drop down so that i get a result.. How to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are programming in html/js?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function elem(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

            function change() {
                var one = elem('1');
                var val = one.value;
                var two = elem('2');
                var content = '';
                if (val == "1") {
                    content = '<option value="1.1">1.1</option>';
                    content += '<option value="1.2">1.2</option>';
                } else {
                    content = '<option value="2.1">2.1</option>';
                    content += '<option value="2.2">2.2</option>';
                }
                two.innerHTML = content;
            }

            window.onload = change;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="1" onChange="change()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

        <select id="2">
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps, but I cannot provide you more help with this unspecific question.

Comment: Yes i am using Html and Js.. for example in the code, i inserted few values in the table, if i select an option in first select box, only valid options shud be shown in the second select box .. ( if in table i have entered many values , if i select A in first select box, then in the second select box only those values should appear whose values are defined with A in the table )

Comment: Have you tried and understood the code above? I showed you the way to do it. I would like you to at least try, I/We can then help you with Problems in your code. This is not a platform to let others write programs for you!